# Pros and cons of using embedded images instead of dynamic loading

Tags: actionscript-3, resources, loading, dynamic

I was just wondering what are the pros and cons of using embedded images instead of dynamic loading? Because when making games on pure AS3 (without Flash IDE), its a pain to manually embed all the assets needed... That makes your code sloppy, besides you don't have control to automatically change the hud, for example, by only changing the external file.

But I heard that some sites only let you upload a single swf, so you can't have external images. Also I heard that some are worried about users downloading their art... But as far as I know, and please correct if I'm wrong, they can also download them if they hack the swf with a decompiler. Having it external, you can encrypt the image, and unencrypt it on the code, so if they try to download they will only get encrypted code.

So... What do you think about embedding images? Please share all your thoughts to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe dynamic loading of images is a better approach. I agree with you about the game problem you stated, but when you are talking of flash/as3 as a whole, games are just one of the things among the many, you do. Also there are a few which also accept multiple files & maybe more will allow later. As of now hosting sites are just being on the safe side by not allowing multiple files & formats. So if you really have additional files you could just host them elsewhere & call them from your main swf.

I however cant agree about the point of making the code sloppy by managing images dynamically. When you do it through an IDE the IDE is writing the code for you, but as you might realize letting an IDE decide what to write doesn't always make the best. Manually handling things let's you understand all entry & exit points of an app. Moreover, would you want to open a flash IDE every time you wish to add an image, make an update, etc.

I usually like to use IDE cause of the awesome tools it provides to make things more efficient & prefer letting the code do all management/control stuff.And yes, if you have many small images (as in online flash games), embedding is better approach.

As far as the security is concerned even externally loaded files can be accessed if the encryption algorithm you use, can be found by decompiling the swf. So your best bet in case of security is usually using a third party software to encrypt the swf, which let's say increases your chance to prevent theft of your material. So if you really encrypt the swf using a 3rd party tool, both the ways would be acceptable.

Comment: This was indeed helpful to me, now I have a better approach to this matter.. In the encryption part you are absolutely right, today they can decrypt everything. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both approaches are valid, it mainly depends on your assets.

As you know embedding assets, will increase the size of your swf, I would only consider doing this for icon type images where size is hardly an issue.

For bigger images, I would definitely go for dynamic loading which I also find more flexible.

Comment: You are right, flexible is the word. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If I have lots of small icons, I'm embedding them. Imagine that number of requests in runtime, any of which may timeout. Pain of embedding, where? A single Embed tag in source or CSS for an asset. "Constant" assets must be embedded, "variable" ones - loaded.

Edit: OK, I got it. Pain of embedding lots of assets. Here is one idea come to my mind...  Even if you loading something dynamically, you need some list with all filenames? You may take list of files and generate class full of `public static const` members with `[Embed]` attributes, that's fairly trivial. Then you use that class in project and voila, all is in the place. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Pain comes when you have lots of assets. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.